# Fetch Raw frames from capturing video Android Camera

Tags: android

I do not know much about Camera API, though i need to use frames from a capturing video with more then 30fps with a good quality camera(S9).
Can anybody suggest code for the same.
I tried to find fit code for this but i am failed.

Thanks in Advance
Mohit

Comment: Welcome, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly,  Your question is missing a lot of information(Code,stack trace, expected result, what have your tried so far). We will do our best to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky, since not so long ago a component of android JetPack was released, called [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax). Sadly it is still in alpha stage, meaning that you should avoid using it in production since it might have breaking changes in the future. This component was built on top of [Camera 2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary), witch is a low level API for working with camera.

If you plan to use your app in production I highly recommend to use Camera 2 API, it is low level, however you have the full control over the camera.

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) is an example to get you started.